# How do I find where a symbol is defined in lots of static library file on windows10?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to complie a project. The linker throw me an error that the external symbols is unsolved.

I understand that I should tell the linker where the .lib file is to deal with this problem. But how can I find what **exactly** the .lib file is to link with my code, from quite a lot of .lib files.

I search for solution but all assume compiling on Linux OS, though I actually compile my code on windows10 with visual studio 2019....T _ T.....

Maybe I can seaerch for the .lib file by the decorated symbol

`__imp_?GetOutputPort@vtkAlgorithm@@QEAAPEAVvtkAlgorithmOutput@@XZ`

but I don't know how to do....

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dumpbin` command of VS to view the dll dependencies of the target program. The usage method is as follows:

Start -> All apps -> Microsoft Visual Studio 20XX -> Developer Command Prompt for VS 20XX, where XX represents your VS version, I am using VS2022.

Enter: `>dumpbin /dependents FilePath:\xxx.exe`

Here is my example for your reference.(I hide my file paths and dynamic libraries.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps when I am looking for the .dll files after I have compiled and got an .exe.  However I still can not find out which .lib file to link with to get the final .exe executable file.

Comment: @LZB Hi,Whether the program is written by you?

Comment: I write the main.cpp and want to use a 3rd party library which contains quite a few `.lib` files.

Comment: Since this is the main function you wrote yourself, it is up to you to decide which libraries you need to include. I suggest you to use Dependency Walker, it can view information about libraries and help you decide which libraries you need.